# c++ staticメンバ関数の実行される時が知りたい。

Tags: c++

提示コードの各ソースファイルの`///`コメント部内部のコードですが`static`関数の実行される時なのですが
`FrameWork`ファイルの`///`コメント部で`Camera`クラスの関数が実行されますが`Camera`クラスのインスタンスが宣言されるのは`Main`ソースファイルの`Entry`クラスの中の`Game`クラスのコンストラクタです。

###### 質問１、

なぜ宣言していないクラスの関数が使えるのでしょうか？`static`関数だからでしょうか？

###### 質問２、

`static`関数が実行されるのは`Framework`のソースファイルのコードで実行されるのでしょか？また`Camera`クラスのコンストラクタが最初に宣言される時でしょうか？

###### FrameWork

```cpp
// ##################################### フレームワークを初期化 #####################################
void FrameWork::Init_FrameWork()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ""); //ローカルを設定

    if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft) != 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "FreeType を初期化出来ません。" << std::endl;
        assert(0);
    }

    FrameWork::Sprite::Init();  //スプライト
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    FrameWork::Camera::Init();  //カメラ
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    FrameWork::Circle::Init();  //図形
    

}
```

###### Main

```cpp
#include "FrameWork/FrameWork/FrameWork.hpp"

#include "Entry.hpp"

int main()
{
   
    if (glfwInit() == GL_FALSE)
    {
        std::cerr << "glfw を初期化出来ません。" << std::endl;
        assert(0);
    }

    

    std::shared_ptr<FrameWork::Window> window = FrameWork::GenWindowContext(glm::ivec2(800,600),"Game");        
    FrameWork::setCurrentContext(window);
    



    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cerr << "glew を初期化出来ません。" << std::endl;
        assert(0);
    }




    FrameWork::Init_FrameWork();
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    std::unique_ptr<Entry> entry = std::make_unique<Entry>();
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    while (*window)
    {
        entry->Loop();

        window->SwapBuffers();
    }
    




    return 0;
}
```

###### Game

```
Game::Game() : Scene(Sequence::Game)
{
    camera = std::make_shared<FrameWork::Camera>();
    canvas = std::make_shared<Canvas>();
    control = std::make_shared<Control>();

    std::vector<std::string> texture;
    texture.push_back("texture/skybox/left.jpg");
    texture.push_back("texture/skybox/top.jpg");
    texture.push_back("texture/skybox/bottom.jpg");
    texture.push_back("texture/skybox/front.jpg");
    texture.push_back("texture/skybox/back.jpg");

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    GLuint t = FrameWork::LoadTexture_CubeMap(texture);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
  //  camera->setSkyBox(t);

    canvas->camera = camera;
    canvas->control = control;

    control->setCamera(camera);

}
```

###### Camera

```cpp
// ##################################### static 初期化　##################################### 
void FrameWork::Camera::Init()
{
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  printf("Init()\n");
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //レンダリングポリゴン
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &quadVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &quadVBO);

    shader = std::make_shared<FrameWork::Shader>();
    shader->Load("shader/FrameBuffer.vert", "shader/FrameBuffer.frag");

    shader->setEnable();
    glBindVertexArray(quadVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quadVBO);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 24 * sizeof(float), &quad, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint attrib = shader->getAttribLocation("vertexPosition");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(attrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(attrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    shader->setBindAttribLocation("vertexPosition");

    attrib = shader->getAttribLocation("vertexUV");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(attrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(attrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), (void*)(2 * sizeof(float)));
    shader->setBindAttribLocation("vertexUV");

    shader->setDisable();
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);   

    frameBufferNumber = 0;
}

// ##################################### 初期化　##################################### 
FrameWork::Camera::Camera()
{       

    

    //MSAA バッファ
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBufferFBO);  
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferFBO);  
    glGenTextures(1, &frameBuffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, frameBuffer);
    glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 8, GL_RGB, windowContext->getSize().x, windowContext->getSize().y, GL_TRUE);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + frameBufferNumber, GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, frameBuffer, 0);
    

    //レンダリングバッファ
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
    glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 8, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, windowContext->getSize().x, windowContext->getSize().y);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);

    //MSAA　アタッチ
    GLuint attachment = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + frameBufferNumber;
    glDrawBuffers(1,&attachment);
    

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        std::cerr << "Framebuffer is not complete: 0x" << glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) << std::endl;
        assert(0);
    }
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);


    //深度マップ
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &depthMapFBO);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthMapFBO);
    glGenTextures(1, &depthMap);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, windowContext->getSize().x, windowContext->getSize().y, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap, 0);

    //カラーバッファ
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &colorBufferFBO);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, colorBufferFBO);
    glGenTextures(1, &colorBuffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffer);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, windowContext->getSize().x, windowContext->getSize().y, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + frameBufferNumber, GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffer, 0);    // we only need a color buffer

    

    /*
    //スカイボックス
    skyBoxShader = std::make_shared<FrameWork::Shader>();

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &skyBoxVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &skyBoxVBO);

    skyBoxShader->Load("shader/SkyBox.vert", "shader/SkyBox.frag");

    skyBoxShader->setEnable();
    glBindVertexArray(skyBoxVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, skyBoxVBO);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 3 * sizeof(float) * 36, &skyboxVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint attrib = skyBoxShader->getAttribLocation("vertexPosition");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(attrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(attrib, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    skyBoxShader->setBindAttribLocation("vertexPosition");

    skyBoxShader->setDisable();
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    */




    position = glm::vec3(0,0,10);   //座標
    vecLook = glm::vec3(0,0,-1);    //向き

    setPosition(position);
    setLook(vecLook);

    frameBufferNumber += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> なぜ宣言していないクラスの関数が使えるのでしょうか？

そもそも「宣言」を正しく理解していない可能性があります。C++言語には「宣言」と「定義」が存在します。次のような記述となります。

```
// 宣言
namespace Framework {
  class Camera {
    ...
    void Init();
    ...
  };
}
```

```
// 定義
namespace Framework {
  void Camera::Init() {
    ...
  }
}
```

```
// 宣言と定義を同時に行う
namespace Framework {
  class Camera {
    ...
    void Init() {
      ...
    }
    ...
  };
}
```

その上で、「宣言」と「定義」を混同されていると思われます。本当に宣言されていない場合はコンパイルエラーとなります。コンパイルに成功していることから`FrameWork::Init_FrameWork()`の当該行より手前に「宣言」は存在するのではないでしょうか？

---

> `static`関数が実行されるのはFrameworkのソースファイルのコードで実行されるのでしょか？

質問の意図が理解できませんでした。特別なことは何もありません。`FrameWork::Init_FrameWork()`関数が呼び出され、その中で`FrameWork::Sprite::Init();`が実行し終わった後で`FrameWork::Camera::Init();`が実行されます。